# preview external image in QTextEdit pyqt/pyside

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qtextedit

I have WYSIWYG editor based on QTextEditor using Python and PySide/PyQt4 and I need to insert an image from a website into it as `<img>` tag but it just add it as small icon.

The code to insert the image is below:

```
url = 'http://yoursportsfeeder.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/ap-patriots-ravens-football-720x400.jpg'
self.text.setHtml('<img src="%s" />' % url)
```

when executing this code I get the icon like the picture below (just a small white icon)

[image]

How can I get the picture preview?

Comment: A `QTextEdit` will only display local images in an `<img>` tag, so you cannot use remote resources directly.

Comment: save image to a variable as base64 encoded (you can use urllib/request), then add it as html

Comment: I think I will do so, save it locally first and display